# How to make left align for distance in latex and distance?

Tags: gamma-function

```
 \begin{eqnarray*}
1+9(\frac{1}{4})^4+17(\frac{1}{4}\frac{5}{8})^4+25(\frac{1}{4}\frac{5}{8}\frac{9}{12})^4+.........=\frac{2\surd(2)}{\surd(\pi) \Gamma^2 \frac{3}{4}}
\end{eqnarray*}

 \textbf{Goldbach’s Conjencture:}\\
 As being a religious devotee Ramanujan did not necessarily believed in writing his methods and procedures in details which confused many mathematicians and it was hard\\
 to follow and understand him right a way they needed genius mind as of Ramanujan’s to explain what’s happening. Goldbach’s conjuncture is an important illustration of Ramanujan’s contribution\\
 towards the proof of conjecture. It states that every even integer greater than 2 is sum of two primes. Ramanujan and his team had shown that every large integer could be written\\
 as the sum of at most four prime numbers\\
 i.e. $43 = 2+5+17+19$\\
 -Euler’s Constant\\
 -Ramanujan derived many formulas for$\Pi$ and $\frac{1}{\Pi}$\\
 Ramanujan investigated and discovered the series (1/n) and calculated Euler’s constant up to 15 decimal places.\\
It is considered that bRamanujan’s contribution to formulas for Euler’s constant From his notebook it is found that:\\
```

----**this sentence appear in latex not align  ! and other sentence like that
what the order in latex to make it align ?**

Comment: This is probably more suitable to ask at [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: It is generally a very bad idea to force a newline.  In this case, I suspect your problem is that newline don't get `parindent`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on TeX/LaTeX SE.

Comment: thanks for help @user10354138

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange H M. This is a Latex question, not a math question. You should ask it at https://tex.stackexchange.com/. Also, what sentence exactly do you mean? The last one? What sentences do you want to align? Try to be more precise in your question.

Comment: any sentences in generally